# how connect to mssql named instance

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2012, named-instance

I connected remote mssql default instance like

> jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip:port;databaseName=name

it succeed to connect and proceed in java source

I connected remote mssql named instance like

> jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip:port;databaseName=name

(surely I set port to instance in SQL server configuration management TCP/IP IPALL)

It succeed to connect, but not proceed well in java source like router error??

I think only reason is named instance

I don't write English well.. But, Help me..

Comment: Please provide actual JDBC connection string used, and a screenshot of your named instance TCP/IP settings.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC doesn't care about instance names, it doesn't use those. The instances are identified by port number.

You need to set up your named instance to allow TCP/IP protocol, assign it a port in TCP/IP IPall *that's different from the default instance port*), then restart the named instance. Then you use that port to connect to it throught JDBC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i did that method yet. when I connect jdbc, I use port (it connected named instance) than It has error.
However when I connect jdbc, I use port (it connected default instance) than it hasn't error.
So I want to know another problem with named instance. Or I want to know another way to connect jdbc with named instance. Or What should I do another setting? T.T Help me..

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem!! The reason is program installing error and than not build essential DB Data. So connect succeed but not proceed well in program.
However I don't know why cause the installing error. it seems to DB authority or named instance... So please you take care of install any program with connect mssql named instance DB. Thank you...